# Get Firebase invite data in onActivityResult()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

In Firebase invites, when onActivityResult() is called after sending them out, is it possible to retrieve information about those invites?

The only thing I've managed to get are the invite IDs:

```
String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
```

But I would also like to get whether the invite was sent via email or SMS, and potentially the email address/phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Just going by what the API exposes, it appears that this is not possible.  AppInviteInvitation does not have any other public methods on it.  Also there is no mention in the documentation of this feature.